# Deployment of jBPM on server

Tags: jbpm

I played with install.demo and start.demo on my PC with windows 7. 
I liked jBPM and now I want to place it at windows or better linux server for my company stuff usage. I can't find any info about deployment jBPM on a server for further work.

Are there any instructions or documentation about deploying jBPM on the server?

P.S. I'm a Python programmer, and I don't know many about servlets and its reuse.

Thanks

Comment: It will work as simple WAR. just copy war files and paste of any server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The demo install does initialize a (WildFly) server, copies the war there and starts the server.  If you want to do it yourself, simply pick up the right version of the kie-wb.war (there are different versions for wildfly, as7, eap, etc.) and deploy it on your server, and configure authorization for user.  Take a look at the install script if you need details on what is done exactly in the installer.